# How to get current processed element in a report?

Tags: c#, rdlc

I'm using Microsoft's reporting framework to design a master-detail report. I use subreports to handle this scenario, and I need a way to identify the current processed element in the master report, so that I can provide the subreport with the right child item it needs.

Currently, I'm thinking about using Ids in my model to uniquely identify items. But How about passing just the index of the currently processed element as a subreport parameter? Is this possible with MS reporting framework? If yes, how can I do it?

Comment: I don't know the microsoft reporting but if it has subreports it HAS to have the ability to pass parameter as it's made for that. In the sub report you should be able to create parameters. Create what you need to filter the table for what you want to display. Then on the master report, in the detail section where the sub report is you should have a right click option or something to allow you to hook a table field of the master report to the subreport parameter

Comment: I can indeed pass parameters, but there doesn't seem to be an option to pass the index of currently processed element. Plus, I am working with business objects, not a database, which makes things a bit different.

Answer (score 0):

The way to accomplish what I think you need is to:

- bind your main report to dataset which would contain your "indexes of elements to be processed",
- place table with one column and no header or footer in your main report and bind it to this dataset,
- place your subreport into that single cell of the table (above) and pass parameter into your subreport as value of the field of your "index" dataset:

  ```
  =Fields!MyIndex.Value
  ```

Comment: I get the idea but I think that it's a bit hackish. I think I'll go with the id solution: Passing the id of the current element to the subreport.

Comment: well, yes, this would exactly accomplish what you just described - passing current ID as a parameter to the subreport.